# Terminology for the category including all of dialogues, monologues, asides and soliloquies

Tags: terminology, theater

As far as I can understand, a play's script might come not only in a conventional dialogue but also in monologues, asides and soliloquies along with stage directions. I'm unable to find a single term referring to them as a collective whole. Is there a predefined literary term used for this very purpose?

Comment: Are you looking for a singe term that covers "dialogues, monologues, asides and soliloquies" (see question title) or a term that covers "monologues, asides and soliloquies" but not "conventional dialogue" (question body)? Could you please edit your question to clarify this?

Comment: @Tsundoku if it helps, I edited the question body away from vaguely saying "forms", and omitted "dialogue" because I thought having it on the same sentence already implied its existence as part of the group.

Comment: Is this more complex than ‘lines’?